# Saving web page HTM as Text file Programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, save

I need to save particular page `HTM` as a `text` file automatically, for example after every 30 seconds.
Programically 
Example - page : csgo2x.com,
then I press `Ctrl` + `S` I can save this file into my PC with save type of `text`.

[image]

> But how to save it programmatically with c++ or c#?

Comment: Why -vote ? Comment please, argue the reason.

Comment: Show at least some effort you made.

Comment: @armandasalmd Your question is very unclear. So you basically want to know how to do plain text formatted output in C# or C++?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: There are too many different ways to approach this making the question too broad. For retrieving web pages you may want to check out [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Qt Library and QWebkit.
Create QWebFrame object.
Use [QWebFrame::load](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#load) function to navigate url.
Call [QWebFrame::toHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#toHtml) function to obtain html.
Use [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html) to save to disk.